# Android. How to record the microphone over audio stream?

Tags: android, audio, microphone, mediarecorder

In my application playing music, the user should say at this time into the microphone. Can you please tell me how to make a record? Music and top path from the microphone. I looked through MediaRecorder, but there is not, in my opinion, an appropriate recording source.

Answer (score 0):

**For Recording Through Mic**

Start and stop recording through Mic....

**Start Recording**

```
static MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
static String path, filename, time;
static int duration;
     public void startRecording() { 
        try {  
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();  
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);  
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.RAW_AMR);    
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);  
            System.currentTimeMillis();
            filename = ListenCallState.number + "_" + time + ".amr";
            File f = new File(getBaseURL());
            f.mkdirs();

            path = getBaseURL() + filename;
            recorder.setOutputFile(path);
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();

        } catch (Exception {
        }
    }
```

**Stop Recording**

```
public static void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        try {
            MediaPlayer p = new MediaPlayer();
            p.setDataSource(path);
            p.prepare();
            duration = p.getDuration();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
 }
```

Comment: I know how to record from the microphone. But how to write music that is playing on your phone and microphone in one track ...

Comment: 1). song is Playing in background    2).in Your Application Record Through Mic.  That is Simple... If You are Talking...Loudly then your voice is also recorded......

Comment: Yes, but the sound quality of the music will be bad (

Comment: Nooo, I can not find the answer

Comment: I think  If you make your own player then that is Possible to record!!