# Streaming the audio from a microphone through a LAN Wi-Fi network

Tags: android, sockets, networking, android-networking

I'm trying to create a mic app to use inside a conference as real mics for audience.We will connect Android devices to Wi-Fi LAN and anybody could trigger the mic from their app to say something to others. The data will go to a server Java programme inside the LAN and to the speakers from there.

Dont know how to get this done.Can someone help me???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Absolutely amazing idea about Android APIs - not sure why it got 5 downvotes. At least mic recording, network discovery and streaming recorded voice are needed.

Answer (score 1):

i think the easiest solution is [WEBRTC](https://webrtc.org) 
you can use webrtc inside your android program , it can handle Microphone/Video itself without any redundant code / plugin / library 
you can use it via https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

> WebRTC standards require the use of  three IEFT NAT traversal standards to address these issues:
>
> Interactive Connectivity Establishment (ICE) –  RFC 5245 Session 
>   Traversal Utilities for NAT (STUN) – RFC 5389 Traversal Using Relay 
>   NAT (TURN) – RFC 5766

so you don't need to handle Client to Client packet transport if you want to use Internet gateways. 
there are also bunch of SO threads which you can read it and use it 
1. [Stream Live Android Audio to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server) 
2. [Streaming voice between Android Phones over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238376/streaming-voice-between-android-phones-over-wifi) 
3. [Android. How to record the microphone over audio stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39292272/android-how-to-record-the-microphone-over-audio-stream) 
4. [An extensive project: Streaming audio from microphone to Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998860/an-extensive-project-streaming-audio-from-microphone-to-android-device)